# Change perspective of a PyOpenGL widget

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I am trying to change the perspective of my scene in a PyQt5 OpenGL widget. I know I have to override some methods, but I do not know which one should I use.

```py
def initializeGL(self):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

def paintGL(self):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    # More code
```

Where should I use the `glOrtho` function? And where can I found information about overriding this methods?
When I go to the declaration of this methods, they have a pass statement and nothing else, how and when are they executed? Should I use `QPainter` instead of OpenGL?

```py
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._x = 0
        self._y = -0.3
        self._z = 0.5
        self._rz = 0
        self._ry = -0.5
        self.vertices_vertical = [[1000, 1000, 000], [1000, -1000, 000],
                                  [-1000, -1000, 000], [-1000, 1000, 000]]
        self.vertices_horizontal = [[1000, 000, -1000], [1000, 000, 1000],
                                    [-1000, 000, 1000], [-1000, 000, -1000]]
    def initializeGL(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glOrtho(0, 1000, 750, 0, -1, 1)

    def paintGL(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glBegin(GL_LINES)

        glColor3d(1, 0, 0)
        glVertex3d(0, 0, 0)
        glVertex3d(1, 0, 0)

        glColor3d(0, 1, 0)
        glVertex3d(0, 0, 0)
        glVertex3d(0, 1, 0)

        glColor3d(0, 0, 1)
        glVertex3d(0, 0, 0)
        glVertex3d(0, 0, 1)

        glEnd()
        # glLoadIdentity()

        glTranslate(self._x, self._y, self._z)
        glRotate(self._ry, 0, 1, 0)
        glRotate(self._rz, 0, 0, 1)

        glEnable(GL_BLEND)
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_DST_COLOR)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glColor4fv((0, 1, 0, 0.6))
        for vertex in range(4):
            glVertex3fv(self.vertices_vertical[vertex])
        glColor4fv((1, 0, 0, 0.6))
        for vertex in range(4):
            glVertex3fv(self.vertices_horizontal[vertex])
        glEnd()
        glDisable(GL_BLEND)
```

Comment: You want to change the projection. Do you want to use [Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Orthographic_projection) ([`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml)) or do you want to use [Perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) ([`gluPerspective`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml))?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I would like to use a Ortographic projection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) the current matrix is a global state. There are different kind of matrices, for each kind of matrix exists a matrix stack. The top of the matrix stack is the current matrix. The matrix stack which is the target for subsequent matrix operations like [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml), [`glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml), [`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml),etc. can be chosen by [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml).

Each vertex coordinate ([`glVertex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml)) is transformed by the model view matrix (`GL_MODELVIEW`) and the projection matrix (`GL_PROJECTION`).

Chose the projection matrix mode in `initializeGL`. Set the [`Identity matrix`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) and set the orthographic projection by `glOrtho`. Note, [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) dose not only set a matrix, it defines a [Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Orthographic_projection) matrix and multiplies the current matrix by the new matrix.

e.g. Set an orthographic projection, which transforms "window" coordinates to the normalized device space. In the following (`windowdWidth`, `windowHeight`) is the size of the window:

```py
def initializeGL(self):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0, windowdWidth, windowHeight, 0, -1, 1)
```

Use the model view matrix mode to set the model view transformations, before you draw the model:

```py
def paintGL(self):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    # model view transformations
    # [...]

    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    # [...]
    glEnd()
```

Comment: @PepeElMago33 Where do you do `glTranslate`? What does it do and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: I have just added the paintGL function. I use that function to move the "camera" in the space, I know I am moving everything

Comment: @PepeElMago33 The orthographic projection changes the scale of the projection. When you use `glOrtho(0, windowdWidth, windowHeight, 0, -1, 1)`, then a translation 0.5 is a half pixel. Use `glOrtho(0, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1)` or `glOrtho(-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1)` to see the difference.